# Finding an entry point for a SCORM 2004 package

Tags: php, iframe, scorm, scorm2004

Following is the code I am using this time to run a simple SCORM package(with a index.html its working). I tried sequencing example from [HERE](http://scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/golf-examples/) package run - [Simple Remediation 
SCORM 2004 3rd Edition](http://scorm.com/wp-content/assets/golf_examples/PIFS/SequencingSimpleRemediation_SCORM20043rdEdition.zip) but this package do not have any index.html file, so how do i check the entry point for running it in the below code ?

I believe I need to check something in `imsmanifest.xml` but unable to locate([googled](https://www.google.com/?q=finding%20the%20entry%20point%20of%20a%20SCORM%20package%20to%20run#bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=6e1bd70740fc41e&q=finding%20the%20entry%20point%20of%20a%20SCORM%20package%20to%20run) a lot but unable to crack).

Let me know how to find an entry file for a SCORM2004 package to run?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Play SCORM Package - </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is going to play a course in an inframe.
        <div id="course-show">
        <iframe src="SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js" name="API_1484_11" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
        <iframe src="course/sample_SCORM2004/index.html" width="800" height="600"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

APIWrapper downloaded from - http://www.adlnet.gov/adl-releases-scorm-version-1-2-and-scorm-2004-api-wrapper-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works like this: the `imsmanifest.xml` lists items and their resources, like this:

```
   <item identifier="playing_item" identifierref="playing_resource">...</item>
   <resource identifier="playing_resource" href="shared/launchpage.html?content=playing" adlcp:scormType="sco" type="webcontent">...</resource>
```

You have to find the first `item` item (sorry :), then use its `identifierref` attribute to find the resource for that item, then use the `href` attribute for that resource to launch. So in your case you have to run `shared/launchpage.html`, not `index.html`.

Also, I'm not sure if your code will work, because you are putting `SCORM_2004_APIWrapper.js` and `index.html` (or `launchpage.html`) into different iframes, so it's likely they won't be able to communicate.

Comment: I tried this way..but then only a blank frame appears..however when I uploaded the same SCORM package in `cloud.scorm.com` it also shows the left panel and text in the frame..let me know what I am doing wrong??

Comment: When you open the shared/launchpage.html, it will try to establish communication with LMS. Then it will display the contents, in this case the "Play of the game" article. If it fails, it will just remain a blank white frame with two buttons below and a bunch of JS errors in the console.

The nice blue stuff around the course in the Scorm Cloud is the Scorm Cloud Player, which is not part of the course. It's the functionality of LMS that disects the package, determines number of items and presents an interface to navigate between those items.

Comment: hey thx for the reply I just have an another issue..stuck from more than 8 hrs :( could you please help me with this if you can ? Not too big just a hint would be sufficient though :)